# How to use PHP to check form field for specific value?

Tags: php, forms, validation

How to use PHP to check form field for specific value?

The value '7' would need to be inserted or else the form field will be invalid; so invalid with all other numbers then 7.

```
if(empty($_POST['captcha']))
{
    $this->add_error("Did you solve the captcha?");
    $ret = false;
}
```

Works to check if any value -- but I need to specify, must be 7.

```
if(strlen($_POST['captcha']) =!7) // tried this but form completely died or disappeared
{
    $this->add_error("Did you solve the captcha?");
    $ret = false;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jack this was the answer, man. If you wanted to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to note here:

1. You shouldn't use `empty()` here, because `"0"` is considered empty as well and it seems like it could be the answer of an equation; use `isset()` instead to just check whether the value is part of the request.
2. You're trying to check the length of `$_POST['captcha']` instead of comparing its value.

So:

```
if (!isset($_POST['captcha']) || $_POST['captcha'] != 7) {
    $this->add_error('Did you solve the captcha?');
    $ret = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

`=!` should be `!=`. See [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
if(strlen($_POST['captcha']) != 7)
```

You also need to turn on [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/250259).